# Use a different port with RequireHttps filter in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, https

Is it possible to use `[RequireHttps]` filter with a different port other than 443? I can't find much documentation about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Steve Sanderson's approach](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/08/05/adding-httpsssl-support-to-aspnet-mvc-routing/) finally worked fine for me. No need to use the MVC2 filters.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass it and override HandleNonHttpsRequest().  From within that method, you can manipulate the URL as necessary.  (For example, you can call base.HandleNonHttpsRequest(), then modify the filterContext.Result property to include a port number.)  Then use [MyCustomRequireHttps] instead of [RequireHttps] on your actions.